# Powershell script Param block validation requires a type defined in another script

Tags: powershell, parameters, add-type

`one-script.ps1` looks like this:

```
. $PSScriptRoot\another-script.ps1 

Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [MyEnum]$enum
)


write-host "hi"
```

`MyEnum` is defined in `another-script.ps1`:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    public enum MyEnum {
        a, b, c, d
  }
"@
```

Running `one-script.ps1  -enum badValue` prints the validation exception as expected, but doesn't stop and prints "hi" as well. The reason I assume is that the Param block can't be preceded by the import statement.

However if I move the import statement below the Param block, the script fails because MyEnum type is undefined.

So how can I use MyEnum class while also having the validation check failure stop script from executing?

One solution is to add MyEnum in user profile, but it's not a good general solution to this problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you have dependencies on your powershell scripts, you should consider to create Powershell Modules

Comment: Tried that. Having import-module before Param block has same effect as dot sourcing - it breaks validation.

Comment: You still using a script, not a module.

Comment: if I'm not wrong `Param` must be the first command in your script to work correctly

Comment: @ jisaak I don't understand what you mean. Can you describe how to solve my problem?