# How to load assembly before param block of a Powershell script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, types, .net-assembly

i'm trying to write a powershell **script** file that has `Parameter`s whose types require loading. A simple code example is below: `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]` requires loading of `system.windows.forms`.

The problem is, the `Param(...)` block must be the very first in the script file. So:

- i cannot place `Add-Type` as the first line in the file.
- i tried with `using assembly system.windows.forms` but it errors out saying: `Cannot load assembly 'System.Windows.Forms'`. I think it could be possible by explicitly writing the dll file path, but it's ugly and not device-agnostic

So what can i do? Here's the code sample.

##### messagebox.ps1

```
# Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms # DOESN'T WORK, can't be placed before Param()
# using assembly System.Windows.Forms # DOESN'T WORK, can't find the assembly to load

Param(
    [string] $Text = '',
    [string] $Caption = '',
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons] $Buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK # REPORTS: Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons].
)
    
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Text, $Caption, $Buttons)
```

**Thanks**

---

A similar question (about a user defined type, instead of a system type):
[Powershell script Param block validation requires a type defined in another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935834/powershell-script-param-block-validation-requires-a-type-defined-in-another-scri)

Comment: Please note: as i implied in my own first answer, i don't want to break parameters autocompletion

Comment: Maybe put `Add-Type` in a separate script and do `using module Otherscipt.ps1;`

Comment: @Charlieface that's a nice idea, unfortunately i just tried and powershell throws the `unable to find type` error **before** importing the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is ***no* good solution as of PowerShell 7.3.3**.

However, there is a - **cumbersome** - **workaround** that **preserves parameter validation and tab-completion**:

```bash
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $Text = '',
    [string] $Caption = '',
    # Implement tab-completion.
    [ArgumentCompleter({
      Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
      [enum]::GetNames([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons])
    })]
    # Given that we cannot strongly type the parameter,
    # make sure whatever value is passed is *convertible* to the desired type.
    [ValidateScript({ 
      Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
      $null -ne [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons] $_
     })]
    # Do NOT type-constrain the parameter (implies [object]).
    $Buttons = 'OK'
)

# Must still ensure the assembly is loaded here, because
# it hasn't bee loaded yet if neither tab-completion was used
# nor a -Buttons value was passed.
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Text, $Caption, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons] $Buttons)
```

Note how the `Add-Type` calls now happen inside parameter-attribute *script blocks* and the function *body*, which bypasses the syntax problem.

---

##### Background information:

- The problem is that parameter declarations are parsed at script *parse time*, which comes before *runtime*, i.e. before actual execution of the script, and any .NET types *directly* referenced in such declarations *must already be loaded* into the session.
- Not just [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type), but - perhaps surprisingly - also `using assembly` loads the referenced assembly's type *at runtime*, and execution of a script never happens if the *parsing* stage fails.

  - That is, even though a [`using assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#assembly-syntax) statement is *syntactically allowed* before a `param(...)` block (unlike `Add-Type`), it does *not* help here - its execution would come *too late* (note that the linked documentation is incorrect as of this writing; an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10828) has been raised).
  - As an aside: As of PowerShell 7.4.1, `using assembly` - is actually *fundamentally broken* for *well-known* assemblies - see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856).
- The underlying problem also affects the use of types in `class` definitions - see [GitHub issue #18482](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18482) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104097/45375).

  - Fixing this limitation has been green-lit years ago, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet, as of the time of this writing - see [GitHub issue #2074](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2074#issuecomment-428299006)
- Finally, a related problem exists in conjunction with [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using#module-syntax) statements that contain `class` and `enum` *PowerShell* definitions: Even though `using module` generally *does* make these available at parse time and therefore allows them to be referenced in other `class` definitions in the the *body* of the caller's script, they too cannot be used *inside `param(...)` blocks* - see [GitHub issue #19676](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19676).

Comment: Urgh almost feels like PS is getting worse not better at this stuff, and it was bad to start with.

Comment: @Charlieface, I wouldn't say it's getting worse, but it's certainly taking its time at getting better - these issues have been known for years.

Comment: damn... that's scary. my actual final script would also have 3 more parameters from that assembly: having to do all of this for each parameter would be absurd :\ i thought that i could at least use `using assembly` with an absolute path but i didn't try it...

Comment: @aetonsi, yes, it is inconvenient, but currently the only solution if you want both tab completion and type safety. As noted in the answer, `using assembly`  - whether with a known assembly name or a full path - does _not_ help. A fix has been green-lit many years ago, but no one has stepped to implement it yet - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3641#issuecomment-297151112

Comment:  i'm going to use this for now.. thank you mr. Klement as always 

Answer (score 1):

The best solution i've found by now is enclosing everything into an IISB (immediately invoked scriptblock) and splatting `$args`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms

& {
param(
    [string] $Text = '',
    [string] $Caption = '',
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons] $Buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK
)

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Text, $Caption, $Buttons)

} @args
```

but this is ugly and it breaks autocompletion obviously, because the `Param()` now belongs to the scriptblock instead of the script